# Predicting missing data. Looking for good data predicting technique

Tags: data-mining, statistics, probability, data-science-model, data-analysis

I am analysing data for Countries Trade GDP. Some of the countries have missing GDP value for given a year. However, I have Grand Total for the entire region for that year. Is there a good data science technique to fill the missing Trade in GDP for the below example.

[image]

Comment: The sample size (i.e., 1 entry for Czech in 2016) is probably too small for any meaningful extrapolation unless you also have some historic data for the country with missing data. @JirkaB's approach is very sensible if your option is limited.

Answer (score -1):

there are several ways how to interpolate the missing data depending on how long history record do you have available:

- you can compute ration of GDPs r_i (where all r_i sums to 1) in year Y-1 of each state with missing values in year Y; then you know the amount of GDP in year Y which should be spread among missing (GDP_total - GDP_known) and multiply by r_i
- a more sophisticated way would be computing the gradient from the timeline Y-1, Y-2, Y-3, ... and you predict a value for year Y for each missing state; then you would again compute ration r_i among missing and distribute remaining GDP accordingly. This regression can be done also backward if you know Y+1, Y+2, Y+3, ... or interpolation from Y-1 and Y+1.

Answer (score -2):

depending on the tools you’re using. But in Python I came across this forum where something similar was asked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532518/fill-in-a-blank-dataframe-column-with-all-0-values-using-python

I hope this helps.